# How to get installed ram and usable ram use WMI Classes?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

i want write on console infor of memory include installed ram and usable ram:
ex: installe memory: 4,00 GB(3,80 GB usable).
currently, i did get "installe memory: 4,00 GB"

```
 public static void GetInstalledMemoryInfor()
    {
        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Capacity FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        UInt64 capacity = 0;
        foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in mos.Get())
        {
            capacity += (UInt64)WmiObject["Capacity"];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Installed memory (RAM): {0:N} GB", capacity / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)));
    }
```

how to get usable ram ? thanks 4 help me?

Comment: The entire physical memory is usable. It depends on who you're asking, to figure out the amount of *accessible* memory. If you're asking the physical memory, all you get as an answer is: "Hey, I'm here. Go ahead, use me!"

Answer (score 1):

Same question was asked and answered 3 days later.

[TotalPhysicalMemory from VisualBasic.Devices slightly different from WMI Win32_PhysicalMemory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903988/totalphysicalmemory-from-visualbasic-devices-slightly-different-from-wmi-win32-p)

Summary:
`Win32_ComputerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory` is what you are after.